# Trying to find the average of multiple values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key, average, key-value

New to python here. Trying to get find the average of totaled up keys in a dictionary.

I've managed to grab the total of all values for each key, but I'm not certain how to find the average of these new values.

```
import os

f = open("iris.data", "r")
count = 0
d = {}
# You want the dictionary to have d = {Iris-setosa: list of values]
# Populate dictionary
# Code would work regardless of file
# Reference movie names file

for line in f:
    if line.isspace():
        continue #If a particular line is made of just spaces, ignore it
    strip = line.strip("\n") #Strips out that particular string
    data = strip.split(",")
    name = data[4]

    if name in d:
        for i in range(len(data)-1):
            d[name][i] += float(data[i])
        d[name][4] += 1 #increment count
        count += 1
    else:
        d[name] = [float(i) for i in data[0:4]]
        d[name].append(1) #keep count
        count = 1
print(d)

f.close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already store a count with each list of values; simply loop over the dictionary *items* (key-value) pairs and use the last element of the value lists:

```
for key, values in d.items():
    avg = [v / values[-1] for v in values[:-1]]
    print(key, *avg)
```

This uses the last element of each `values` list as the row count, and uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to produce an average value for each of your columns.

Some other remarks:

- you evidently have a CSV file; consider using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) instead.
- you never *called* the `f.close()` method; you merely referenced it.

  However, you should consider using the file object as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types) instead. The [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) ensures that the file is closed for you when the block is exited:

  ```
  with open("iris.data", "r") as f:
      for line in f:
          line = line.rstrip('\n')
          if not line:
              continue
  ```

Comment: You're a saint and scholar sir. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the values to a list, then sum, and divide by the length of the list:

```
values = d.values()
average_value = sum(values) / len(values)
```

Since the values are lists, perhaps you can get the average for each list:

```
for v in d.values():
    average_value = sum(v) / len(v)
```

Comment: This treats each list as a collection of values; the OP is already summing CSV values however; 4 separate columns are each summed based on a key, with a fifth value in the list being the number of summed rows.

Comment: In other words; the OP is looking for 4 averages per key. Not 1 average per key.