# adding simple mathematical operation to python script

Tags: python

I have a program that operates on a csv file to create output that looks like this:

```
724, 2
724, 1
725, 3
725, 3
726, 1
726, 0
```

I would like to modify the script with some simple math operations such that it would render the output:

```
724, 1.5
725, 3
726, 0.5
```

The script I'm currently using is here:

```
lines=open("1.txt",'r').read().splitlines()
for l in lines:
    data = l.split('"Overall evaluation:')
    if len(data) == 2:
        print(data[0] + ", " + data[1])
```

How could I add a simple averaging and slicing operation to that pipeline?

I guess I need to create some temporary variable, but it should be outside the loop that iterates over lines?

Maybe something like this:

```
lines=open("EasyChairData.csv",'r').read().splitlines()

for l in lines:
    data = l.split('"Overall evaluation:')

    submission_number_repo = data[0]

    if len(data) == 2:
        print(data[0] + ", " + data[1])

        if submission_number_repo != data[0]
            submission_number_repo = data[0]
```

---

**EDIT**

The function is just a simple average

Comment: what is the function that maps the 72X to Y ?

Comment: why first line should be 2.5 not 1.5?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to find the average of multiple values in a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451046/trying-to-find-the-average-of-multiple-values-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: that was a typo- the function is just a simple average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary that map the key to the total and count and then print it:

```
map = {}
lines=open("1.txt",'r').read().splitlines()
for l in lines:
    data = l.split('"Overall evaluation:')
    if len(data) == 2:
        if data[0] not in map.keys():
            map[data[0]] = (0,0)
        map[data[0]] = (map[data[0]][0]+int(data[1]) , map[data[0]][1]+1)
for x, y in map.items():
    print(str(x) + ", " + str(y[0]/y[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just store an list of values with the key. Then take the average when file is read.

```
lines=open("1.txt",'r').read().splitlines()
results = {}
for l in lines:
    data = l.split('"Overall evaluation:')
    if len(data) == 2:
        if data[0] in results: 
            results[data[0]].append(data[1])
        else: 
            results[data[0]] = [data[1]]
for k,v in results.iteritems():
    print("{} , {}".format(k, sum(v)/len(v) ))
```

Comment: Save all the values is unnecessary and inefficient

Comment: @OhadEytan sure but lets start with understanding the concept then we can optimize. so is storing all the lines of the file for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

(Edited to avoid storing of values)

I love `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
average = defaultdict(lambda: (0,0))
with open("1.txt") as input:
    for line in input.readlines():
        data = line.split('"Overall evaluation:')
        if len(data) != 2:
            continue
        key = data[0].strip()
        val = float(data[1])
        average[key] = (val+average[key][0], average[key][1]+1)

for k in sorted(average):
    v = average[k]
    print "{},{}".format(k, v[0]/v[1])
```

Comment: Save all the values is unnecessary and inefficient

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to keep a state storing current number, current sum and number of items, and only print it when current number changes (do not forget to print last state!). Code could be:

```
lines=open("1.txt",'r')  # .read().splitlines() is useless and only force a full load in memory
state = [None]
for l in lines:
    data = l.split('"Overall evaluation:')
    if len(data) == 2:
        if data[0] != state[0]:
            if state[0] is not None:
                average = state[1]/state[2]
                print(state[0] + ", " + str(average))
            state = [data[0], 0., 0]
        state[1] += float(data[1])
        state[2] += 1
if state[0] is not None:
    average = state[1]/state[2]
    print(data[0] + ", " + str(average))
```