# Find min, max, average and total rainfall on Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I need assistance in getting the min/max/average/total from a dictionary.  Is one that gets pulled vice inputted into these [].

def main():

def rainfall():

```
print( "Printing Dictionary\n" )

months = []  # Emptly list to populate
# dateime is not zero based so we have to start loop with 1
for monthinteger in range(1, 13):
    # %B retrieves the month see https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datetime.asp
    retrieved_month = datetime.date(1900, monthinteger, 1).strftime(
        '%B')  # You could have used any year
    months.append(retrieved_month)

rainfall = dict()
for rain in months:
    rainfall[rain]= random.randint(0,4)

print(rainfall)

return rainfall
```

this is what I used before for a list but it is not working for this type of dictionary

def minrain_maxrain(months_dictionary):

```
minrain = months_dictionary.keys
maxrain = months_dictionary.keys

for rain in months_dictionary.keys() :
    if (maxrain < n[1]) :
        maxrain = n[1]

    if (minrain > n[1]) :
        minrain = n[1]   

for n in minrain_maxrain :
    print( n[0], n[1] )
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really intended to provide homework help, but rather to catalogue solutions to common programming problems. You should always look for generic solutions (eg [Finding the average of values in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451046/trying-to-find-the-average-of-multiple-values-in-a-dictionary)) before you post, and if you do post, try to make it independent from the overarching problem so that it can help as many people as possible.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic problem: sorting based on dictionary values Python

Python developers are new friendly

I hope you don't care what others say

```
import random
import datetime

def rainfall():
    print( "Printing Dictionary\n" )

    months = []  
    for monthinteger in range(1, 13):
        retrieved_month = datetime.date(1900, monthinteger, 1).strftime('%B')  
        months.append(retrieved_month)

    rainfall = dict()
    for rain in months:
        rainfall[rain]= random.randint(0,4)

    return rainfall

sort_rain = sorted(rainfall().items(), key=lambda item:item[1], reverse=True) # you can try reverse=False 

max = sort_rain[0][1]
max_month = sort_rain[0][0]
min = sort_rain[-1][1]
min_month = sort_rain[-1][0]
print(max)
print(max_month)
print(min)
print(min_month)

rain_sum = sum( d for d in rainfall().values())
average = sum( d for d in rainfall().values()) / len(rainfall())

print(rain_sum)
print(average)
```

Comment: Nah, I don’t care what ppl say, but I appreciate your help!